# Will there an error in some situation?

Tags: arrays, swap, shuffle

I have another question
I have card deck, I shuffle this deck. My method is swap some pairs.

```
while count < m:
    swapcard = random.randint(0, m-1)
    buffer = cdgi[count]
    cdgi[count] = cdgi[swapcard]
    cdgi[swapcard] = buffer
    count = count + 1
```

Question - in situation when `count` was like `swapcard`, was there error?
For example:

```
cdgi[15] = cdgi[15]
```

Comment: I don't know... fatal may be. (I newbie)

Comment: Indentation is **not optional** in python.

Comment: so you're asking us if swapping a card with itself would cause an error? this isn't a real example of something you've done, you're just fishing for answers?

Comment: Why don't you just **test** it? Simply use something like `swapcard = count`... Also, why don't you use `random.shuffle()`?

Comment: Test, I think you are right, a make another copy and simulate this situation.

Comment: random.shuffle() - I don't know about this function, thanks for advice!

Comment: Yes ThiefMaster - I make a test and nothing happiend.

Answer (score 0):

Good question... I guess it would depend on the language.  I don't think in general it should be an issue, but if you want to be safe, you could put both values to be swapped in temporary variables so you're not assigning to the same variable.